# How to prove the statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all integers $a, b, c$, if $a | c$ and $b | c$, then $ab | c^2$.

How can I prove the statement is wrong or true?

My work so far: $a | c  \land b | c \implies ab | c^2$  where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $a|c$ is $c=ka$ and $b|c$ is $c=hb$. Thus, mult them: $c^2=(hb)(ka)$.

Comment: You cannot prove it with propositional calculus only.

Answer (score 2):

$$ a|c \implies c=k_1 a$$

$$b|c \implies c=k_2 b$$

$$  a|c \text { & }  b|c \implies $$

$$ c^2= k_1k_2 ab  \implies $$

$$ab|c^2$$